# Gurobi on Python: Muting the optimize function

Tags: python, linear-programming, solver, gurobi

I am using Gurobi on Python and my code requires a loop of Model.optimize() function. Is there a way to mute this function, so it won't make paragraphs of output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [**Output Flag**](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/outputflag.html) parameter to zero.

From the reference manual on output flag:

> Enables or disables solver output. Use LogFile and LogToConsole for
>   finer-grain control. Setting OutputFlag to 0 is equivalent to setting
>   LogFile to "" and LogToConsole to 0.

a code chunk from a project I am working on:

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, LinExpr, quicksum

dual_subproblem = Model('dual_subproblem_(0,0)')
dual_subproblem.setParam('OutputFlag', 0)  # Also dual_subproblem.params.outputflag = 0
dual_subproblem.params.threads = 1 
dual_subproblem.modelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE
dual_subproblem.update()
```

Then the call to optimize does not produce any output.

I hope this helps.